# hibernate lazy load exception after deep clone using Serialization

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**TLDR:** I am using `Spring-jpa` and `Hibernate` in my project, My problem occured only after I'm trying to get a List of objects that defined as `Lazy` in the entity that I deep cloned using `org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone()` method.

I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at sei.persistence.wf.entities.Element_$$_jvstc68_47.getNote(Element_$$_jvstc68_47.java)
    at JSON_to_XML.createBpmnRepresantation(JSON_to_XML.java:139)
    at JSON_to_XML.main(JSON_to_XML.java:84)
```

After I am trying to get a List of all `users` that defined as `lazy` in `duplicateEvent` object

**The Code :**

```
@Service
public class EventService {

@Autowired
EventRepository eventRepository;

 public List<User> duplicateEvent(Long id) {
    Event event =  eventRepository.findById(id);
    Event duplicateEvent = SerializationUtils.clone(event);

    return duplicateEvent.getUsers();
  }
}
```

**Event Entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="events")
public class Event implements Serializable{

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name="id")
 private Integer id;

 @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="event")
 privare List<User> users = new ArrayList();

  public List<User> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
  }

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public Event() {

  }
}
```

p.s : `spring.jpa.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true` property didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out myself

instead of deep copy with `org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.clone()`

I used [Dozer Mapper](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/about.html) for deep copy , and there is no exception anymore.